# validate a form when using modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, semantic-ui

I try to make a form validation, but if I hit submit, the form disapears before giving me the feedback:

```
<div class="ui right aligned grid">
    <div class="ui three wide column">
        <div class="ui center aligned inverted orange segment"> 
            <div class="ui animated fade large inverted button" onclick="contact()">
              <div class="visible content">Say Something!</div>
              <div class="hidden content">Express yourself ;)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui first coupled modal">
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">
tell me something
</div>
<div class="content">
<form class="ui form" method="post" action="/msg">
    <h4 class="ui dividing header">What do you think</h4>
    <div class="field">
      <label><i class="write icon"></i></label>
      <textarea name="txt" class="field" placeholder="write something" required></textarea>
      <input class="ui green button" type="submit" value="gtt"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui small second coupled modal">
<div class="header">
<i class="red heart icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="description">

    <h1>Thank you</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <div class="ui approve inverted blue button">
    <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    Bye ^_^
  </div>
</div>
```

The `JS`:

```
 function contact(){
         $('.coupled.modal')
          .modal({
            allowMultiple: false
          })
        ;
        // attach events to buttons
        $('.second.modal')
          .modal('attach events', '.first.modal .button')
        ;
        // show first now
        $('.first.modal')
          .modal('show')
        ;    
    }
```

And here is how the first windows diseapears without letting me validate.
[image]

Update: I added the validation, but it doesent work:

```
$('.ui.form')
  .form({
    message: {
    identifier  : 'msg',
    rules: [
     {
      type   : 'empty',
      prompt : 'Please enter a message'
     }
   ]
      },
   })
```

;

Comment: Where is your `contact()` function called?

Comment: @D4V1D sorry, I update the question, because contact is called only when clicking on the button.

Comment: You've separated your HTML code, are there multiple HTML files?

Comment: no, at the end they are one, the separated is done on server (`tornado`)

Comment: Have you any errors in the console?

Comment: @D4V1D nothnig, I added the picture about what happens between the first window and the second one.

Comment: Your picture is showing HTML 5 validation as controlled by the browser itself as per your HTML 5 attributes; nothing to do with JavaScript.  If you need more control over validation, you could write your own JavaScript or use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: semantic ui offers validation too, http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#/examples I will try this if it captures.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the onApprove and onDeny callbacks to perform the logic?

The fact that the modal fades but that the dimmer stays on the screen suggests an error in the js. Go to the debugger and find out.